# GET Request giving status of 500

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, get, prisma

I am using Prisma, NextJS, and NextAuth for authentication. I have a route to get the user after they are logged in to display their name and username on the homepage. Here is the code for the route:

```
import prisma from '../../../lib/prisma'
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import { unstable_getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";

export default async function handler(
    res: NextApiResponse,
    req: NextApiRequest
) {
    const session = await unstable_getServerSession(res, req);
    const email = session.user?.email
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            email,
        },
    })
    res.status(200).json(user)
}
```

I have the following useState on the homepage:

```
    async function getUser() {
        const response = await fetch('/api/auth/getUser', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
        const data = await response.json()
        setUser(data)
        console.log(data)
    }
    getUser()
```

When I load the page, my browser console gives the following message:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`
It does not give any more information, so I don't really know what to do. Is it a dumb mistake in one of my functions? TYA

Comment: Check the logs of the server.

Answer (score 0):

The order of req/res matters. Using `(req,res)` instead of `(res,req)` fixes this issue.